# linq after groupby unable to get column values

Tags: c#, sql, linq, join, group-by

I am getting data from multiple tables by joining and i want to group data on particular column value but after group by statement i can access my aliases and their properties. What mistake i am making?

```
public List<PatientHistory> GetPatientHistory(long prid)
{
    using(var db = new bc_limsEntities())
    {
        List<PatientHistory> result = 
            (from r in db.dc_tresult
             join t in db.dc_tp_test on r.testid equals t.TestId into x
             from t in x.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join a in db.dc_tp_attributes on r.attributeid equals a.AttributeId into y
             from a in y.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where r.prid == prid
             group new {r,t,a} by new {r.testid} into g
             select new PatientHistory
             {
                 resultid = r.resultid,
                 bookingid = r.bookingid,
                 testid = r.testid,
                 prid = r.prid,
                 attributeid = r.attributeid,
                 result = r.result,
                 Test_Name = t.Test_Name,
                 Attribute_Name = a.Attribute_Name,
                 enteredon = r.enteredon,
                 Attribute_Type = a.Attribute_Type
             }).ToList();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. Once you've grouped, each element of the sequence is a group - `r` doesn't exist as a range variable any more, there's just `g`, the group... which you're completely ignoring. It looks like you've misunderstood the purpose of `group` clauses.

Comment: but i can't access the properties with g variable

Comment: how to access the column using g variable

Comment: Well `g` is the *group* - it's all the records with the same testid, because that's what you've grouped by... Again, it's really not clear what you're trying to achieve

Comment: i need the columns that i am selecting grouped according to testid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing this wrong way. As been said by Jon after grouping the sequences with aliases `r`,`t`,`a` doesn't exist. After grouping you receive the sequence `g` with sequances of `r`,`t`,`a` in each element of `g`. If you want get one object from each group (for example most recent) you should try this:

```
List<PatientHistory> result = 
    (from r in db.dc_tresult
     join t in db.dc_tp_test on r.testid equals t.TestId into x
     from t in x.DefaultIfEmpty()
     join a in db.dc_tp_attributes on r.attributeid equals a.AttributeId into y
     from a in y.DefaultIfEmpty()
     where r.prid == prid
     group new {r,t,a} by new {r.testid} into g
     select new PatientHistory
     {
         resultid = g.Select(x => x.r.resultid).Last(), // if you expect single value get it with Single()
         // .... here add the rest properties
         Attribute_Type = g.Select(x => x.a.Attribute_Type).Last()
     }).ToList();
```

Comment: i applied this query but when i iterate in foreach loop for getting results, cnonection timeout exception comes, server did not responded for a long time, why its hapeening? @YD1m

Answer (score 0):

I appreciated this question so I thought I would add another potential usage case.  I would like feedback on what the cleanest approach is to getting table information through a group operation so that I can project later in the select operation. I ended up combining what the OP did which is to pass objects into his group clause and then used the g.Select approach suggested by YD1m to get table information out later.  I have a LEFT JOIN so I'm defending against nulls :

```
// SQL Query
//DECLARE @idCamp as Integer = 1
//
//select *, 
//(select
//count(idActivityMaster)
//FROM tbActivityMasters
//WHERE dftidActivityCategory = A.idActivityCategory) as masterCount
//FROM tbactivitycategories A
//WHERE idcamp = @idCamp
//ORDER BY CategoryName

int idCamp = 1;
                
var desiredResult =     
(from c in tbActivityCategories 
    .Where(w => w.idCamp == idCamp)
from m in tbActivityMasters
    .Where(m => m.dftidActivityCategory == c.idActivityCategory)
    .DefaultIfEmpty()   // LEFT OUTER JOIN      
 where c.idCamp == idCamp                    
 group new {c, m} by new { m.dftidActivityCategory } into g
 select new
 {                      
    idActivityCategory = g.Select(x => x.m == null ? 0 : x.m.dftidActivityCategory).First(),
    idCamp = g.Select(x => x.c.idCamp).First(),
    CategoryName = g.Select(x => x.c.CategoryName).First(),
    CategoryDescription = g.Select(x => x.c.CategoryDescription).First(),                       
    masterCount = g.Count(x => x.m != null)
 }).OrderBy(o=> o.idActivityCategory);                                       
                 
desiredResult.Dump("desiredResult");
```

[image]

If I just use a basic group approach I get the results but not the extra column information.  At least I can't find it once I group.

```
var simpleGroup = (from c in tbActivityCategories
                     .Where(w => w.idCamp == idCamp)
                     .OrderBy(o => o.CategoryName)
                 from m in tbActivityMasters
                    .Where(m => m.dftidActivityCategory == c.idActivityCategory)
                    .DefaultIfEmpty()   // LEFT OUTER JOIN      
                 where c.idCamp == idCamp
                 group m by m == null ? 0 : m.dftidActivityCategory into g
                 select new
                 {
                    // How do I best get the extra desired column information from other tables that I had before grouping
                    // but still have the benefit of the grouping?
                    // idActivityCategory = g.Select(x => x.m == null ? 0 : x.m.dftidActivityCategory).First(),
                    // idCamp = g.Select(x => x.c.idCamp).First(),
                    // CategoryName = g.Select(x => x.c.CategoryName).First(),
                    // CategoryDescription = g.Select(x => x.c.CategoryDescription).First(),
                    // masterCount = g.Count(x => x.m != null)                      
                    idActivityCategory = g.Key,
                    masterCount = g.Count(x => x != null)                                               
                 });
                 
simpleGroup.Dump("simpleGroup");
```

[image]

Please tear this up.  I'm trying to learn and it just seems like I'm missing the big picture here.  Thanks.

UPDATE : Cleaned up by moving the work into the group and making the select more straight forward.  If I had known this yesterday then this would have been my original answer to the OP question.

```
int idCamp = 1;

var desiredResult =
(from c in tbActivityCategories
    .Where(w => w.idCamp == idCamp)
 from m in tbActivityMasters
     .Where(m => m.dftidActivityCategory == c.idActivityCategory)
     .DefaultIfEmpty()   // LEFT OUTER JOIN      
 where c.idCamp == idCamp
 group new { c, m } by new 
 {  idActivityCategory = m == null ? 0 : m.dftidActivityCategory,
    idCamp = c.idCamp,
    CateGoryName = c.CategoryName,
    CategoryDescription = c.CategoryDescription     
 } into g
 select new
 {       
     idActivityCategory = g.Key.idActivityCategory,
     idCamp = g.Key.idCamp,
     CategoryName = g.Key.CateGoryName,
     CategoryDescription = g.Key.CategoryDescription,
     masterCount = g.Count(x => x.m != null)
 }).OrderBy(o => o.idActivityCategory);

desiredResult.Dump("desiredResult");
```